# SQLAlchemy order by hybrid property that references relationship

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My SQLAlchemy models:

```
class Cover(db.Model):
    # ... a bunch of other fields ...

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_requests(self):
        if self.requests:
            return len(self.requests)
        return 0

    @number_of_requests.expression
    def number_of_requests(cls):
        return func.count(cls.requests)

class Request(db.Model):
    # ... a bunch of other fields ...

    # Cover that this request is requesting
    cover_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('cover.id')
    cover = db.relationship('Cover',
                        backref=backref("requests", cascade="all, delete-orphan"))
```

So, a simple one-to-many relationship between Cover and Request. The `number_of_requests` hybrid property should return the number of Requests associated with that particular Cover.

Now, in one of my Flask routes, I'm trying to grab the top 5 Covers by number of Requests. Here's what that looks like now:

```
# Get top cover requests
covers = Cover.query.order_by(Cover.number_of_requests).limit(5).all()
```

Unfortunately, this gives

> ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) missing FROM-clause entry for table "request"

I suspect this is because in `number_of_requests(cls)` I'm trying to count the size of the `requests` list but SQLAlchemy hasn't included the request table in the original query. Any ideas on how to do that to avoid getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `expression` part to:

```
@number_of_requests.expression
def number_of_requests(cls):
    return (select([func.count(Request.id)])
            .where(Request.cover_id == cls.id))
```

and read [`Correlated Subquery Relationship Hybrid`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid) again.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any way I can do that without having to import Request?

Comment: I guess you could do something like below, but basically you could use plain `sql` in this case. Ideally you need either a class `Request` or a table `request` thought. Should work for simple queries where you do not have aliases and multiple joins on the `Cover`: `(select([func.count('request.id')]).select_from('request').where("request.cover_id == cover.id"))`

Comment: Great, small change though: changed "request.cover‌​_id == cover.id" to "request.cover‌​_id = cover.id" and it works.

Comment: @van can one return list of related objects with eg limit in hybrid_propery /expression combo?

Comment: @andilabs: I am not sure I understand the question in the context of this answer. Would you not just have use the `relationship` for related objects? maybe just a read-only with some special WHERE clause to select only top N related objects.

Comment: @van I need example for case like customer and having a property like last_10_purchases

Comment: @van I wen for smth like this https://gist.github.com/andilabs/b4b715a1dd884110803cfc49929373bb

Comment: @andilabs: please check this documentation page: [Row-Limited Relationships with Window Functions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#row-limited-relationships-with-window-functions). You can use the example to construct a query for the `expression` part of your hybrid attribute.