# SQLAlchemy: Order query by count

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to order the query result by the number of likes a post has received.
This is my Table:

```
class Card(Base):
   __tablename__ = 'cards'
   id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
   post_id = Column(Integer)
   voted = Column(Boolean)

@hybrid_property
def likes(self):
   likes = session.query(Card).filter(and_(Card.post_id == self.post_id, Card.voted == True)).count()
   return likes

@likes.expression
def likes(cls):
   return (select([func.count(Card.id)]).where(and_(Card.post_id == cls.post_id, Card.voted == True))
```

This is the query:

```
cards = session.query(Card).filter(Card.user_id == current_user.get_id()).order_by(desc(Card.likes)).all()
```

The order_by part in SQL, which seems quite right to me:

```
ORDER BY (SELECT count(cards.id) AS count_1 FROM cards WHERE cards.post_id = cards.post_id AND cards.voted = true) DESC
```

But when I'm calling this after the query:

```
for card in cards:
    print card.likes
```

The output is not in descending but completely random order. My only guess now is that because of the filter, the count is only executed at those cards with card.user_id == current_user.id. If so (?), how do I order my query result by the total number of likes a post has received?

Things I looked up before: Hybrid Attributes [1](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior), SQLAlchemy order by hybrid property [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836076/sqlalchemy-order-by-hybrid-property-that-references-relationship),

Thank you.

Comment: That SQL is definitely not right. `cards.post_id = cards.post_id` is always true, so every row has `count_1` equal to the number of total cards with `voted = true` in the table, meaning the sort will just give you rows in no particular order. Can you elaborate on how `Card`, `Post`, and "likes" tie together? Otherwise we can't really suggest a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that you want to query `Card` and not the `Post` instances (ordered by number of votes their cards received)?

Answer (score -3):

To be honest I don't see how your sql statement even works, below is the reference to postgresql order by.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-order.html
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_having_clause.htm

And I believe your query should be rewritten like so:

### SQL:

```
SELECT count(cards.id) AS count_1, cards.id
FROM cards
GROUP BY count_1
HAVING cards.voted = true
ORDER BY count_1 DESC
```

But even then it looks wrong to me, can we see your ERD?