# Generate sql with subquery as a column in select statement using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, correlated-subquery

Is there a way to make SQLAlchemy generate a query with a custom column that is a subquery that correlates with current row:

```
SELECT
 tab1.id,
 tab1.col1, 
 ...,
 (
     SELECT count(1) FROM tab2 
     WHERE tab2.tab1_id = tab1.id
     GROUP BY tab2.col1
 ) as cnt
FROM tab1
WHERE ...
LIMIT 100
```

using the ORM API?

```
session.query(Tab1, ?(subquery for additional column)?).filter(...).limit(100)
```

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and old version of SQLAlchemy 0.9.8

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need this often, and/or the count is an integral part of your `Tab1` model, you should use a hybrid property such as described in the other answer. If on the other hand you need this just for a single query, then you could just create the scalar subquery using [`Query.label()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.label), or [`Query.as_scalar()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.as_scalar):

```
count_stmt = session.query(func.count(1)).\
    filter(Tab2.tab1_id == Tab1.id).\
    group_by(Tab2.col1).\
    label('cnt')

session.query(Tab1, count_stmt).filter(...).limit(100)
```

The subquery will [automatically correlate](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/tutorial.html#correlated-subqueries) what it can from the enclosing query.

Comment: Thanks. Lifesaver. Note that `as_scalar` is deprecated in 1.4 and should be replaced with `scalar_subquery`.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this, but it works in a quite different way to how you have written it. You can create a property of Tab1 which depends on the relationship to tab2 (assuming that `tab2.tab1_id` is a foreign key, which it should be.

Your models look like this:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child")

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'child'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parent.id'))
```

as per [the docs on relationships](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html)

Then you can add something like

```
@hybrid_property
def number_of_children(self):
    if self.children:
        return len(self.children)
    return 0

@number_of_children.expression
def number_of_children(cls):
    return (select([func.count(Child.id)])
            .where(Child.cover_id == cls.id))
```

to the Parent model, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25836076/sqlalchemy-order-by-hybrid-property-that-references-relationship) and [more docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#correlated-subquery-relationship-hybrid).

Once you've done this, you can filter on this property the same as any other column-based one.

Answer (score 1):

### For SQLAlchemy 2 users

Simply define a `select` statement for your sub-query statement. You can then use it as a column in another `select` statement.

Using Ilja Everilä's example:

```py
count_stmt = (select(func.count(1))
              .where(Tab2.tab1_id == Tab1.id)
              .group_by(Tab2.col1)
              .scalar_subquery()
              .label('cnt'))
```

More details are in the [SQLAlchemy 2.0 documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/data_select.html#scalar-and-correlated-subqueries).