# Nested session.query using sqlalchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am completely new in SQL Alchemy. I am trying to convert below sql into sql alchemy but not getting desire result. My query:

```
select   locationkey
,(select geo.value from locations__geo_coordinates geo where l._id=geo._sdc_source_key__id and geo._sdc_level_0_id=0) as latitude
,(select geo.value from locations__geo_coordinates geo where l._id=geo._sdc_source_key__id and geo._sdc_level_0_id=1) as longitude 
from locations l
```

I am trying to get result by using **session.query(**. Whatever I found is on SELECT but that also giving error.

Comment: You should provide more information, maybe share your model definitions.

Comment: Perhaps this will be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43655840/6560549

Comment: @SuperShoot Thnaks. It helped me.